# boxed equation but framed only some sides

Tags: equations, boxes, framed

I need to box part of an equation, but I need the frame to be open one side. In the following MWE I would need the left part of the equation not to have the right frame of the box and the right part of the equation not to have the left frame of the box.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
This is my equation $\boxed{q_1^{\ast}}=\dfrac{26-2\cdot 1 -4\cdot 2}{2\cdot 1}=\boxed{8}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following MWE provides `\lboxed` and `\rboxed` which are truncated `\fbox`es. Technically, this is identical to `\fbox` only with the right/left `\vrule` removed (the definition of `\fbox` is taken from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)). It also provides `\llboxed` and `\rrboxed` which are `array`-style boxes with the required side stripped of its vertical rule.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\lboxed}[1]{\begin{array}{|l}\hline#1\\\hline\end{array}}
\newcommand{\rboxed}[1]{\begin{array}{r|}\hline#1\\\hline\end{array}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\llboxed}[1]{{%
  \let\@frameb@x\l@frameb@x\fbox{#1}%
}}
\newcommand{\rrboxed}[1]{{%
  \let\@frameb@x\r@frameb@x\fbox{#1}%
}}

\def\l@frameb@x#1{%
  \@tempdima\fboxrule
  \advance\@tempdima\fboxsep
  \advance\@tempdima\dp\@tempboxa
  \hbox{%
    \lower\@tempdima\hbox{%
      \vbox{%
        \hrule\@height\fboxrule
        \hbox{%
          \vrule\@width\fboxrule
          #1%
          \vbox{%
            \vskip\fboxsep
            \box\@tempboxa
            \vskip\fboxsep}%
          #1%
          %\vrule\@width\fboxrule% Right \vrule removed
                    }%
        \hrule\@height\fboxrule}%
                          }%
        }%
}
\def\r@frameb@x#1{%
  \@tempdima\fboxrule
  \advance\@tempdima\fboxsep
  \advance\@tempdima\dp\@tempboxa
  \hbox{%
    \lower\@tempdima\hbox{%
      \vbox{%
        \hrule\@height\fboxrule
        \hbox{%
          %\vrule\@width\fboxrule% Left \vrule removed
          #1%
          \vbox{%
            \vskip\fboxsep
            \box\@tempboxa
            \vskip\fboxsep}%
          #1%
          \vrule\@width\fboxrule}%
        \hrule\@height\fboxrule}%
                          }%
        }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
This is my equation $\boxed{q_1^{\ast}}=\dfrac{26-2\cdot 1 -4\cdot 2}{2\cdot 1}=\boxed{8}$

This is my equation $\rboxed{q_1^{\ast}}=\dfrac{26-2\cdot 1 -4\cdot 2}{2\cdot 1}=\lboxed{8}$

This is my equation $\rrboxed{$q_1^{\ast}$}=\dfrac{26-2\cdot 1 -4\cdot 2}{2\cdot 1}=\llboxed{$8$}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any reason not to define `\let\@frameb@x\l@frameb@x\fbox{$#1$}` instead to ease the use of `\rrboxed` and `\llboxed`? I've tried it and the log doesn't seem to give any error.