# Half table border in Math (see example)

Tags: tables, math-mode, border

I need like this half table border.

[image]

Please help me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Maybe you can adapt [this solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106288/40974) to your problem.

Or have a look at the packages [`empheq`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/empheq) and [`mdframed`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed). For the latter, [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40315/40974) answer might be related.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{|ll}\hline
 a & b\\
 c & d\\
\end{tabular}`

Comment: @Fran thanks, I edit your comment and get result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with some help by `array`.

Since there are both complex superscripts and subscripts, I chose to issue `\displaystyle` in every cell of the array, which raises them a bit.

Second trick: (locally) increase the apparent height of the cells, in order to better separate them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1.5ex} % more room
\begin{array}{ | *{4}{>{\displaystyle}l} @{\qquad} >{\displaystyle}l }
\hline
X_{1}^{(1)} & X_{1}^{(2)} & X_{1}^{(3)} & X_{1}^{(4)} & \sim 1-e^{-t^{2}} \\
X_{1}^{(1)} & X_{1}^{(2)} & X_{1}^{(3)} &             & \sim 1-e^{-2(t^{2}-x^{2})} \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem by this code:

[image]

```
\[\left| \!{\overline {\, 
 \begin{array}{l}
 {X_1}^{(1)}‎\hphantom{x}‎{\rm{  }}{X_2}^{(1)}‎\hphantom{x}{\rm{ }}{X_3}^{(1)}‎\hphantom{x}{\rm{ }}{X_4}^{(1)}‎\hphantom{xyz}‎\sim{1-e^{-t^2}}‎ \\ 
 {X_1}^{(2)}‎\hphantom{x}{\rm{ }}{X_2}^{(2)}‎\hphantom{x}{\rm{ }}{X_3}^{(2)}‎\hphantom{xyzwasda}‎\sim{1-e^{-2(t^{2}-x^{2})}}‎ \\ 
 \end{array} \,}} \right. \]‎‎‎‎
```

But if your math formula is simple, `@Fran`'s answer is nice *(This comment was little need to edit.)*

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{11|}\hline a & ‎b‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎\\‎
c & d‎‎‎‎‎‎\\ ‎\end{tabular}‎
```

❤️ Thank's all users for their comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplfiy your code in this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{|cccc@{\hspace{2em}}l}
\hline\\[-1em]
X_1^{(1)} & X_2^{(1)} & X_3^{(1)} & X_4^{(1)} & ‎\sim 1-e^{-t^2}‎  \\[1ex]
X_1^{(1)} & X_2^{(2)} & X_3^{(2)} & & \sim 1-e^{-2(t^{2}-x^{2})}  \\
\end{array} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: `\sim` doesn't take an argument.

Comment: @egreg of course. Nasty effect of the copy & paste `:( `